# Electron webview html string video resize

Tags: javascript, webview, electron, html5-video

I have a problem. Whenever I click the video fullscreen button then instead of the video going fullscreen the main window of the application is going fullscreen. Can't seem to solve this.

Here is some part code:

```
 const getVideoFile = src => {
    const loadView = () => `
    <html>
      <body>
        <video controls style="position: absolute; top: 12px;left: 12px;height: 78%;width: 92%;outline: none;">
          <source src="${src}">
        </video>
      </body>
    </html>`;

    return `data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${encodeURIComponent(loadView())}`;
  };


<WebView src={getVideoFile(currentSrc)} className={classes.webview} />
```

[Problem video showcase](https://streamable.com/2n93j)